# Voodoo behavior in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Ok I know that when you instantiate an object of class that is non-serializable Jenkins will give you `java.io.NotSerializableException`, but I'm experiencing this weird behavior: When I run this Jenkinsfile, it runs without errors:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('First') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def pattern = ~"Version-\\d+.\\d+"
                    def matcher = "Version-2.33" =~ pattern
                    println matcher[0]
                    println matcher[0]
                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No error. But when I add a `powershell` step:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('First') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def pattern = ~"Version-\\d+.\\d+"
                    def matcher = "Version-2.33" =~ pattern
                    println matcher[0]
                    println matcher[0]
                    
                    powershell script: 'echo hello' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

error. Any ideas?